# What does this Eclipse icon mean in a Merge Results view?

Tags: eclipse, icons, subclipse, svn-merge

I just did an svn merge from a branch to a trunk in my Eclipse IDE, and in the Merge Results view, there is this following icon:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2a0a0f90b1.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2a0a0f90b1.jpg)

I am dying to know what it means.  I have searched the entire Eclipse documentation and some relevant StackOverflow questions, but couldn't find anything.

The [CollabNet documentation](http://desktop-eclipse.open.collab.net/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=MEuUjb&freeformpage=Merge%20Client) about Merge Results View explains what a Merge Results View is, but doesn't mention anything about the meanings of its icons.

Does anyone know?  Thanks!

Comment: my *guess* would be "merge conflict"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is the icon for a SVN tree-conflict which is new in SVN 1.6.  Try doing Show Tree Conflicts option and see if the same items appear in the tree conflicts view.  Also see:

http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2009/03/subversion-160-and-tree-conflicts.html

Answer (score 1):

I've just hit up against the same thing.

After a bit of digging around I believe that it means there were changes to the file in both places however the changes are the same, therefore the files are the same.